# Initializer using a string for DataMember returning a static object of the class (factory pattern) in C#?

Tags: c#, static, factory, datacontract, initializer

My first question on StackOverflow, I feel intimidated and excited.

I tryied to have an exact behavior of for a class using static object as factory pattern and being serialized with just a type as string. When deserialized, the Initializer should return the static object based on the string.

It is easier to do over an example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Interpolation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public static Interpolation Linear = new Interpolation(...)
}
```

I'd like to get a Linear interpolation thought different ways:

```
var interpolation = Interpolation.Linear;

var linear = new Interpolation
{
    Type = "Linear"
};
```

The first one is a factory pattern (kind of), the second one is used for the deserialization.

I have trying few solutions. Normally I have a generic constructor, and I am using specific parameters to create the static object. It would become:

```
[DataContract]
public class Interpolation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
            _interpolation = Select(value);
        }
    }

    private string _type = "Linear"; // Default
    private Func<double, double[], double[], double> _interpolation;

    private Interpolation(Func<double, double[], double[], double> interpolation, string type)        
    {
        _interpolation = interpolation;
        _type = type;
    }

    public static Interpolation Linear = new Interpolation(_linear, "Linear");

    private double _linear(double x, double[] xx, double[] yy)
    {
        ...
    }
```

This method won't work if there is no generic constructor (the object is too complicated to be created only from parameters). Also the static object Interpolation.Linear already exists, I don't necessarily want to recreate it.

What I would like is

```
var linear = new Interpolation
{
    Type = "Linear"
};
```

returning

```
Interpolation.Linear
```

A constructor can't return a static object of the class:

```
public  Interpolation(string type)        
{
    return Interpolation.Linear; // Won't work
}
```

Maybe by using Reflection...
Thanks :)

Comment: Please note that the deserialization doesn't call any constructors. The object will be created directly in memory. If you need some custom actions after deserialization, just create a method and mark it with an `OnDeserializedAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is intended to *create* a new instance. If you are trying to use it to return an existing instance, you are doing it wrong. Just stick with a (kind of) singleton

```
var interpolation = Interpolation.Linear;
```

Or use a factory like this

```
public static class InterpolationFactory
{
    public static Interpolation GetInterpolation(string type, Func<double, double[], double[], double> interpolation = null)
    {
        if (type == "Linear")
        {
            return Interpolation.Linear;
        }
        else
        {
            return new Interpolation(interpolation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it would work with a deserialization. When client receives the DataContract with Type = "Linear", I believe it will invoke a parameterless constructor. So my question, when deserializing how to return a static object of the class.

Comment: Regarding the InterpolationFactory class, I was trying to avoid creating a second class for the same type of object. But I totally agree, you can use the value of Type in the DataContract to call a factory class which will return the expected object.

Comment: @isidore12, yep, you should try it. If you'll not succeed I'll give it a try later.

Comment: @isidore12 - as for the serialization/deserialization you may want to consider decoupling - i.e. serialize just the "Type" string - or some InterpolationParameters object if it is more compex; and construct Interpolation instance from Type (or InterpolationParameters) later using factory method.